# Different lists in list have same id in python

Tags: python

I understand that Python mutables like lists have different identities while "special situations" like certain strings and numbers will have the same IDs but I don't understand this situation:

```
>> a = [[0]*2]*2
>>> a
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
>>> id(a[0])
140387455550664
>>> id(a[1])
140387455550664
```

Both [0,0] lists in the list *a* have the same ID

However, when I create a list like this, the IDs are different for each list element in that list

```
>>> b = [[0,0],[0,0]]
>>> id(b[0])
140387455550472
>>> id(b[1])
140387456353480
```

I am using CPython/Python 3.6 on Ubuntu

Comment: They are not different lists..

Comment: OK got it - just saw the duplicate answer/qs - thanks

Comment: `a[0]` and `a[1]` are the same list object, which is why they have the same id. Your question title implies you think they are different lists.

Comment: @MartijnPieters bit off-topic but noticed `id([]) == id([1])` is `True`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Yes, because ids can be re-used. `[]` does not live long enough to keep the id, so it is reused for `[1]`.

Comment: @Chris_Rands: ids are unique *for the objects lifetime only*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Great, thank you, makes sense!